# Wallpaper disappear every time I change it from the command line

Tags: gnome, bash, themes, desktop-background

I searched informations about this error on-line, but it seems that nobody has got this problem. I did a little bash script, that every time I call it, it changes the theme and the wallpaper to night/daymode.

Everything works except that the wallpaper doesn't change, but simply disappear.

I'm currently using ubuntu 19.04 disco dingo with gnome
Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
night(){
echo "starting night mode..."
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Mc-OS-MJV-Dark-Gn3.32-V.2.1"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/Immagini/test.jpg
gnome-tweaks
}

day(){
echo "starting day mode..."
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ant-Nebula"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/Immagini/27p.jpg
gnome-tweaks
}

help(){
cat<<_EOF_
this eBic command let me, and only me, changing my theme and backgroung when it turs out that 
it's night, so it set a dark wallpaper and theme.
Comands:
    light --nightmode = guess
    light --daymode = guess
_EOF_
}

if [ "$1" == "--nightmode" ]; then
    clear
    night
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" == "--daymode" ]; then
    clear   
    day
    exit    
fi

if [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    help
    exit
fi
```

Thank you, I hope somebody will solve this problem.

P.S. Sorry for the english

Comment: Have you tried putting the file name in single quotes, as suggested [here](https://people.gnome.org/~pmkovar/system-admin-guide/background.html)?

Comment: @Bubagna i have tried your code with single quotes as mentioned above.. perfect!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qiH0.gif

Comment: I tryed putting the image path in single quotes, but still not working ):

Comment: Oh, I didn't insert the correct file path into the single quotes, so it wasn't working. However thanks for helping me, sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by Jos. The file path must be between single quotes, and I put it between double quotes.